# Alternatives to AWS ClientVPN

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, vpn, amazon-vpc, aws-vpn

I am hosting a webserver within a private subnet on an EC2 instance. I am looking to be able to connect to a port via my browser to access the website.

I understand I can set up an AWS managed clientVPN which will allow users to log in via a VPN client and access the website. I know port forwarding (via local host) could also be done using systems manager agent however I seem to only be able to access one tab of the port at once and I don't quite understand the security of it.

Does anyone have any other ideas that I could have specific users access the port via their browsers?

Comment: You can specify your IPs in a Security Group? This way only you will have access it the website.

Comment: This will only work if instance has a public ip.